# Invoice ID from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice within sales_order_invoice_pay-event

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem with the data I receive on the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event. I expect that an 'invoice pay' event would have access to the refered invoice? However, `$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();` returns an `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice` that obviously does not contain all data. E.g. I was unable to use `->getId()` on it.

`getData()` returns:

```
array (
  'order_id' => '196',
  'store_id' => '2',
  'customer_id' => '24',
  'billing_address_id' => '196',
  'shipping_address_id' => NULL,
  'global_currency_code' => 'EUR',
  'base_currency_code' => 'EUR',
  'store_currency_code' => 'EUR',
  'order_currency_code' => 'EUR',
  'store_to_base_rate' => '1.0000',
  'store_to_order_rate' => '1.0000',
  'base_to_global_rate' => '1.0000',
  'base_to_order_rate' => '1.0000',
  'discount_description' => NULL,
  'total_qty' => 5,
  'subtotal' => 5,
  'base_subtotal' => 5,
  'subtotal_incl_tax' => 5,
  'base_subtotal_incl_tax' => 5,
  'grand_total' => 5,
  'base_grand_total' => 5,
  'discount_amount' => 0,
  'base_discount_amount' => 0,
  'base_cost' => 0,
  'shipping_amount' => '0.0000',
  'base_shipping_amount' => '0.0000',
  'shipping_incl_tax' => '0.0000',
  'base_shipping_incl_tax' => '0.0000',
  'shipping_tax_amount' => '0.0000',
  'base_shipping_tax_amount' => '0.0000',
  'shipping_hidden_tax_amount' => '0.0000',
  'base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount' => '0.0000',
  'tax_amount' => 0,
  'base_tax_amount' => 0,
  'hidden_tax_amount' => 0,
  'base_hidden_tax_amount' => 0,
  'can_void_flag' => false,
  'state' => 2,
)
```

**How to I get from here to the numeric invoice ID (or increment ID)?** I would like to avoid going through the order_id because of the 1:n connection there.

*I tried:*

```
$invoice->getId();
$invoice->getID();
$invoice->getData('id');
$invoice->getData('entity_id');
$invoice->getIncrementId();
$invoice->getData('increment_id')
```

I am using Magento 1.9.2 CE and the context of this is within a paypal IPN request. The deeper I dive into the code, the more I think that the invoice has not been persisted/created at the time the hook is called?